# PHP trying to move file with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

I have been back forward about this, can't find a solution.  My file that I am trying to upload is not moving.  I'm using WAMP and my root folder is C:\wamp\www

I've checked that the directory exists in php and put in a script that if it does not exist it should be created, which works, but still it is not moving the file.  What am I doing wrong?

The Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Upload.php

```
$target_path = "uploads/" ;
if(!file_exists($target_path)) {
    mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);
    echo "The directory was created";
}
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
echo $target_path;

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: you're just assuming the upload succeeded. you need to check `['error']` in $_FILES **FIRST** before you do anything else.

Comment: Can you also your HTML code as well? and Yes `['error`]` can give more information

Comment: Thank you.  I've added the form in my question above and then I used print_r($_FILES); to check the variable but there is no error:  Array ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => ts.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php48A8.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 803390 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change,

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

to

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: Thank you, now I feel like an idiot!  I have been overlooking that the whole time!